# How to plot pyramid population chart with plotly?

Tags: python, plotly

I'd like to plot a population pyramid chart with plotly. I would like to have My output seems totally wrong. I couldn't find a working solution after much research. Help is much appreciated.

My code:

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.offline as pyo
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame


df = pd.DataFrame({
    'age': ['11', '19', '22', '30', '24', '27', '15'],
    'group': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'B', 'C', 'B'],
    'gender': ['Male','Female','Male','Female','Female','Male','Male'],
    'count':[3,5,6,1,4,5,2]
})

women_bins = df['count']
men_bins = df['count']

y = df['age']

layout = go.Layout(yaxis=go.layout.YAxis(title='Age'),
                   xaxis=go.layout.XAxis(
                       range=[-df['count'].max(), df['count'].max()],
                       title='Number'),
                   barmode='overlay',
                   bargap=0.1)

data = [go.Bar(y=y,
               x=men_bins,
               orientation='h',
               name='Men',
               hoverinfo='x',
               marker=dict(color='powderblue')
               ),
        go.Bar(y=y,
               x=women_bins,
               orientation='h',
               name='Women',
               text=1 * women_bins.astype('int'),
               hoverinfo='text',
               marker=dict(color='seagreen')
               )]

pyo.iplot(dict(data=data, layout=layout), filename='EXAMPLES/bar_pyramid')
```

**Output:**
[image: Chart Output]

Comment: Your additional request is not clear for me.

Comment: @snow Please keep posts focused by only asking one question at the time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use negative numbers to place bars to the left. Adjust the axis tick labels.

```py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.offline as pyo
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame


df = pd.DataFrame({
    'age': ['11', '19', '22', '30', '24', '27', '15'],
    'group': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'B', 'C', 'B'],
    'gender': ['Male','Female','Male','Female','Female','Male','Male'],
    'count':[3,5,6,1,4,5,2]
})
# Of course it was the same, now I separated by gender
women_bins = df['count'][df['gender'] == 'Female']
men_bins = df['count'][df['gender'] == 'Male']

y = df['age']

xtick =list([6,-4, -2, 0, 2, 4, 6])

layout = go.Layout(yaxis=go.layout.YAxis(title='Age'),
                   xaxis=go.layout.XAxis(
                       range=[-df['count'].max(), df['count'].max()],
                       tickvals=xtick,
                       ticktext=[str(abs(x)) for x in xtick],
                       title='Number'),
                   barmode='overlay',
                   bargap=0.1)



data = [go.Bar(y=y,
               x=men_bins,
               orientation='h',
               name='Men',
               hoverinfo='x',
               marker=dict(color='powderblue')
               ),
        go.Bar(y=y,
               x=-women_bins,
               orientation='h',
               name='Women',
               text=1 * women_bins.astype('int'),
               hoverinfo='text',
               marker=dict(color='seagreen')
               )]

pyo.iplot(dict(data=data, layout=layout))
```

[image]

Comment: the graph is incorrect, the outcome of men and women is exactly the same whereas in the data table they aren't..

Comment: Sorry, I just plotted accordingly to the example you gave me. See the definitions of `men_bins` and `woman_bins`